# Как удалить элемент из массива или как сделать двойной выбор рандома?

Tags: java, случайные-числа

У меня есть рандом, который случайно выбирает один из девяти `ImageButton`-ов и меняет в нем картинку (первый уровень игры). Во втором уровне нужно менять картинки у двух `ImageButton`-ов (в третьем - у трёх и т.д) Проблема в том, что рандом часто выбирает одну и ту же кнопку несколько раз и логика игры нарушается. Я вижу два выхода из этой ситуации:

1. После первого рандома удалять выбранную кнопку из массива и "давать" полученный массив второму рандому.
2. Как-то сделать так, чтобы рандом сразу выбирал несколько кнопок из массива.

Какой вариант лучше? И как можно его осуществить?

```
ImageButton[] buttons = { labirint11, labirint12, labirint13, labirint14, labirint15, labirint16, labirint17, labirint18, labirint19 }; //создаю массив с кнопками
                        ArrayList<ImageButton> buttonsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(buttons)); //это что? 


                    long seed = System.nanoTime();
                        Collections.shuffle(buttonsList, new Random(seed)); //перемешиваю?



                    if(buttons[0]==v && buttons[1]==v)
                    {
                        overgame.start();
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.door_wall);
                        tostart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        good.start();
                        buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.door_wall);
                        buttons[1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.door_wall);
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.door_go);
                        next_room.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
```

По идее я меняю картинку у двух первых элементов уже перемешанного массива. Но меняются две самые первые. Потому что я обратился buttons[0] к первому элементу в массиве. Но я же его перемешал....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На каждом уровне создавай новый ArrayList со случайным порядком элементов

```
long seed = System.nanoTime();
ArrayList<ImageButton> buttonsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(buttons));
Collections.shuffle(buttonsList, new Random(seed));
```

А потом просто делай обход элементов в цикле с необходимым для этого уровня количеством итераций.

**UPDATE:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class ShuffleDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] buttons = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; //Для простоты заменим кнопки числами
        ArrayList<Integer> buttonsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(buttons));

        for(int x = 1; x < 5; x++) { //Уровни с 1 по 5
            System.out.print("Level " + x + ":");
            long seed = System.nanoTime();
            Collections.shuffle(buttonsList, new Random(seed));
            for(int y = 0; y < x & y < buttonsList.size(); y++) { //Кнопки на уровне
                System.out.print(" " + buttonsList.get(y));
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Если запустить этот демонстрационный пример, то будет видно, что на каждом уровне выбраны случайные кнопки и никакая из кнопок в выборе не повторяется.

```
Level 1: 2
Level 2: 1 3
Level 3: 5 4 3
Level 4: 2 5 3 4
```

Comment: тоесть последующие выборы рандома сравнивать с предыдущими и в случае сходства просто-напросто повторять операцию?

Comment: После `Collections.shuffle(buttonsList, new Random(seed));` у тебя будет массив со случайным положением элементов. Можно просто выбирать из него элементы по очереди. На каждой итерации у тебя случайный элемент. Проблема того, что рандом часто выбирает одну и ту же кнопку исчезнет.

Comment: ничего блин не получается... Как получать элементы по очереди? :-(

Comment: Я перемешал элементы, да. Но как к ним обращаться? При buttonsList[0] - ошибка, так как ArrayList не умеет работать с ImageButton. А при buttons[0] я обращаюсь к массиву кнопок. Я не могу даже объяснить проблему... Помогите кто-нибудь досконально.

Comment: Для получения элементов ArrayList служит метод get(index). Я отредактировал ответ. Теперь он включает в себя полный, пригодный для компиляции пример.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте массив рандомов и заполняйте его в зависимости от уровня игры. Как-то так:

```
HashSet<Integer> positions = new HashSet<>();
int newRandom;
while (positions.size()<gameLevel) {  
   newRandom = new Random().nextInt(numberOfPictures);
   positions.add(newRandom);
}
ArrayList<Integer> randoms = new ArrayList<>(positions);
```

`HashSet` будет добавлять только уникальные значения. Чтобы потом "брать" из него элементы, нужно перевести его в массив.